# Use Xuggle in Java to trancode and streaming video/audio

Tags: java, android, video, stream, xuggle

I create an HTTP streaming server, but the clients can not play all video formats, so my question is, if there is a way, using xuggle in the server to transcode the video in a specific format and streaming it directly, on the fly.

I mean, not have to wait to finish the transcoding and then start the http streaming. I mean that I have a loop for example and get everytime a number of transcoded bytes and writes them to the socket.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, but...

I'd not recommend taking this approach.  Encoding videos is generally very CPU intensive.  The generally accepted aproach to solving this problem is to transcode the video file off-line and store on the streaming server.  Yes, that means a couple of different media files with the same video, but it scales *muuuuuuuuch* better.  Most (all?) successful streaming servers do it this way.